# Download image and strore in sdcard folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard, filenotfoundexception

I want to download image from url and store in sdcard's folder.
If folder is not exist make folder and save it.
But its giving following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard (Is a directory)
```

Comment: URL myImageURL = new URL("http://"+imageURL);
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)myImageURL.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(path, fileName);
                
                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();

Comment: Its giving exception on  OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: have you added permission in manifest 
 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is clear. **/mnt/sdcard** is a directory not a file. You need to create **FileOutputStream** that writes to a **non-directory** path.

For example:

```
//Setting up cache directory to store the image
File cacheDir=new File(context.getCacheDir(),"cache_folder");

// Check if cache folder exists, otherwise create folder. 
if(!cacheDir.exists())cacheDir.mkdirs();

// Setting up file to write the image to. 
File f=new File(cacheDir, "img.png");

// Open InputStream to download the image. 
InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();

// Set up OutputStream to write data into image file. 
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

HelperUtil.CopyStream(is, os);

...



/**
 * Copy all data from InputStream and write using OutputStream
 * @param is InputStream
 * @param os OutputStream
 */
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size=1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.ghostbook/cache/cache_folder/img.png (No such file or directory)

Comment: You must check if the folder already exists or not too. In this case, check **if(!cacheDir.exists())cacheDir.mkdirs();** This will create all required folders for you.

Comment: its making file not folder. Please help

Comment: Edited my answer with comments and the read/write IOStream. Change Cache folder to point to your SDcard directory. Don't forget to use permission to write file and using internet.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
String image_URL="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fandroid-er.blogspot.com%2F";

String extStorageDirectory;
File file;
Bitmap bm;
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        file=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Your FolderName");
        extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  }else{
        file=YourActivity.this.getCacheDir();
 }
if(!file.exists())
  file.mkdirs();


  extStorageDirectory+="Your FolderName/yourimagename.PNG";
  File imageFile = new File(extStorageDirectory);

  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
  if(bitmap!=null){
  imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }else{
    extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    file=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Your FolderName");

    file=new File(extStorageDirectory, "Your FolderName/yourimagename.PNG");
     try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();



      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

      }
  }
```

where method are as

```
private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options)
 {      
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  InputStream in = null;      
    try {
      in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
   }
  return bitmap;              
}

 private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

  try{
   HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
   httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   httpConn.connect();

    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
      }
  }catch (Exception ex){ 
       Log.e("error",ex.toString());
       }
  return inputStream;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong path when triying to save the picture. IT seems that you use "/mnt/sdcard" whereas it should be something like "/mnt/sdcard/image.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        bm = LoadImage(image_url, bmOptions);
        extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + "/image_folder";

        OutputStream outStream = null;

        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(extStorageDirectory);
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "image.PNG");

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
}
return bitmap;
 }

  private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
InputStream inputStream = null;
URL url = new URL(strURL);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

try {
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.connect();

    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
return inputStream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, that will return the External memory if it is exist, otherwise it will return the phone memory directory. The constructor takes Context and the name of the folder that you want to create as parameters. And also try this link, its quite nice stuff about what you need. [Image Loader](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/tree/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist)

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;
private String applicationDirectory = Config.applicationMainFolder;

public FileCache(Context context, String folderName){
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), applicationDirectory + folderName);
    else
        cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), applicationDirectory + folderName);
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url){
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;
}

public void clear(){
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path);  

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, bytes);
        byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray();
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(b);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

path will be your folder in sdcard and bitamp is object of image